# Login System Using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, authentication

Please i've been trying to login but i seem to be getting the else "username and password not found". I'm not able to login using this code

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'lib/password.php';

if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){
    $errMsg = '';

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);



    if($username == '')
        $errMsg = 'You must enter your username<br>';

    if ($password == '')
        $errMsg = 'You must enter your password<br>';

    if($errMsg == ''){
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $records->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['password'])){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
            header('location:welcome.php');
            exit;
        }else{
            $errMsg = 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
        }
    }

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 if(isset($errMsg)){
 echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:left;font-size:12px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
 }
 ?>
<form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">

<p>If you don't have an account, <a href="register.php">SIGNUP</a></p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem. Please can someone help out?

Comment: Can you narrow down which is failing `count($results) > 0` or `password_verify($password, $results['password'])`? Also do you trim the user's username and password when they create their account?

Comment: make sure that the password column is long enough to accommodate the hash. many a times, that is the root of the problem. If it isn't long enough, you will need to alter the column's length, delete existing data and start again. use varchar(255) which is the recommended length. If your column is 50, then it will fail.

Comment: a little interaction would be nice. It's only been what.... an hour. Good thing for browser tabs.

Comment: and where's `$current_file`? no idea what that's assigned as, or where.

Comment: Do `var_dump($results);`. What does PHP return?

Comment: Thanks. Ihave made the corrections and it's working now.

Comment: those corrections being what?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the password column is long enough to accommodate the hash.

Many a times, that is the root of the problem. If it isn't long enough, you will need to alter the column's length, delete existing data and start again.

Use VARCHAR(255) which is the recommended length.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

From the manual:

> Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

If your column is 50, then it will fail.

Hashes generated by `password_hash()` produce a 60 character string:

**$2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K**

Plus `$current_file` in your file's action; that is unknown to us, so make sure that it has been properly assigned.